# How to use an array of multiple strings out of the loop

Tags: java, arrays

I have printed data from a text file of type double and converting it into an array of double. when I print the array it looks like this

```
[2.0    -2.0    -2.0    -2.0    2.0     2.0    2.0  2.0]    1.39E-04
[-2.0   -2.0    0.0     -2.0    -2.0    0.0   -2.0  2.0]    0.020446
[2.0     0.0    -2.0     2.0    2.0    -2.0   -2.0  -2.0]   0.032339
[2.0     2.0    -2.0    -2.0    2.0     2.0   -2.0  2.0]    0.026673
[-2.0    0.0    -2.0    -2.0    0.0     2.0    0.0  2.0]    0.094135
[0.0     0.0    0.0     -2.0    0.0     2.0    2.0  0.0]    0.045922
[0.0    -2.0    0.0     -2.0    0.0     2.0    0.0  -2.0]   0.117043
[-2.0   -2.0    -2.0     2.0    2.0     2.0    2.0  -2.0]   0.425709
[-2.0   -2.0    -2.0     2.0    2.0     2.0    2.0  2.0]    0.156286
```

The last column is the score of each row that calculated based on specific equation. My question is how can I use this array out of the loop? Because I need to do some process with this array. 
Sorry I need to use the array outside the loop with same structure above but without brackets

The code that I used is like this

```
double []  D =new double [rows]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < cols-1 i++) { 
                List<Double> list=  new ArrayList<Double>();
              for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) { 
               int A = M[c][r];
               D[c] = A;
              list.add(D[c]); 
            } 
double score= M.calculateDistance(D,class);       
                  System.out.println(list+" "+score);
        }
```

Comment: Posted code contains no array. What array do you want tp use "out of the loop"?

Comment: I have updated the code @ElliottFrisch

Comment: make it as a member variable

Comment: please could show me how?@war_Hero

Comment: What is `c` and `r`? Or did you mean `i` and `j`?

Comment: yes. i have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

You can make another list that will hold your array

```
List<List<Double>> listOfList=  new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
```

thus your new code will be like this:

```
double []  D =new double [rows]; 
List<List<Double>> listOfList=  new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
for (int i = 0; i < cols-1 i++) { 
    List<Double> list=  new ArrayList<Double>();
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) { 
        int A = M[c][r];
        D[c] = A;
        list.add(D[c]); 
    } 
    double score= M.calculateDistance(D,class);       
    System.out.println(list+" "+score);
    listOfList.add(list); // add the array
}
```

But if you want to also use the `score` outside your loop and relate it to their specific array, I suggest you use a `Map` or make your own Object.

Comment: but if I transfer this code List<Double> list=  new ArrayList<Double>(); above the loop, the list will store only the first line in the file an repeat it for the whole strings of file

Comment: @aya sorry I misunderstood your question. Refer to the edited answer

Comment: yes it more logic but why give this incompatible types
  required: java.util.List<java.util.List<java.lang.Double>>
  found:    java.util.ArrayList<java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Double>>

Comment: now the error is moved to this line  listOfList.add(list);

Comment: no suitable method found for add(java.util.List<java.lang.Double>)
    method java.util.List.add(int,java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Double>) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.util.List.add(java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Double>) is not applicable
      (actual argument java.util.List<java.lang.Double> cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Double> by method invocation conversion)

Comment: Sorry, I was quite busy and just typed the answer, I have edited it and checked it on an IDE

Comment: ok it is working but why all in one line, i need them as l posted in multiple lines.

Comment: What do you mean all in one line?

Comment: all the data in the above array that i posted